# My website template is aligned to the left side

Tags: python, django, django-templates, static

My code is exceeding the word limit so [you can see the code here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sG_OzlOpejxwmmQftTS-S25l6lgy9giX/view?usp=sharing)

This is my template and when I run the server locally, the webpage is kinda aggined to the left side like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEeuu.png) But in fact, it should look like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmKhY.png). I set the static directory in the settings.py as `STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)` and I loaded the static on the top of the page as shown. Can't figure out the problem.

Comment: check chrome `DevTools` and inspect `body` tag in `css` rules.i think problem is in css files nor server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I have given the variable name:

```py
# settings.py

# this 
STATIC_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

# should be this
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

That solved the problem.